# C# Unity Найти пустые элементы в List и удалить их

Tags: c#, list

Есть List, в котором изначально хранится множество ссылок на объекты в юнити.
В процессе выполнения кода, какие-то из объектов перестают существовать, в связи с чем в List`е появляются пустые ссылки, как от них можно разом избавиться?

Вариант с удалением объекта из списка перед его удалением не подходит.
Возможно есть способ как-то проверить каждый элемент списка на null и все элементы с пустыми ссылками - удалить? Через какой-нибудь foreach, но сам допереть не могу...

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> aa = new List<string> { "sdsds", null, "sdsdsd" };
aa = aa.Where(x => x != null).ToList();
```

или

```
aa = aa.FindAll(x => x != null);
```

Comment: или так `list.RemoveAll (x => x == null);`